# sqlite insert putting values into wrong fields

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to insert this

```
- (void)insertBlogStory:(NSString *)storyTitle link:(NSString *)link storyDescription:(NSString *)storyDescription storyHTML:(NSString *)storyHTML pubDate:(NSString *)pubDate blog:(NSString *)blog {

    NSLog(@"storyTitle %@",storyTitle);
    NSLog(@"link  %@",link);
    NSLog(@"storyDescription  %@",storyDescription);
    NSLog(@"storyHTML  %@",storyHTML);
    NSLog(@"pubDate  %@",pubDate);
    NSLog(@"blog  %@",blog);

    if(addStmt == nil) {

        const char *sql = "insert into contents (storyTitle, link, storyDescription, storyHTML, pubDate, blog, read) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [storyTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [link UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [storyDescription UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [storyHTML UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5, [pubDate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6, [blog UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt,  7, 0);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));

    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);


}
```

Which prints out correct values being sent to the methiod

```
storyTitle -> Converged Security
link -> http://...converged-security.html
storyDescription -> Cyber-crime is not new....etc
storyHTML -> <p>Cyber-crime is not new....etc
pubDate -> Thu, 01 Sep 2011 10:52:57 +0100
blog -> Business continuity
```

The sqlite table looks like this

```
TABLE "contents" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
"storyTitle" TEXT,
"link" TEXT,
"storyDescription" TEXT,
"storyHTML" TEXT,
"pubDate" DATETIME,
"blog" TEXT,
"read" INTEGER,
"storyVideo" TEXT,
"storyVideoThumb" TEXT,
"storyAudio" TEXT,
"issueA" TEXT,
"industryA" TEXT,
"serviceA" TEXT,
"contactName" TEXT,
"contactPhone" TEXT,
"contactAddress" TEXT,
"contactPhrase" TEXT,
"contactPhraseEmail" TEXT,
"contactPhraseName" TEXT
);
```

But this is what is inserted

```
"storyTitle" correct string
"link" correct string
"storyDescription" correct string
"storyHTML" correct string
"pubDate" correct string
"blog" is always NULL
"read" is always NULL


"storyVideo" gets the blog string (Business continuity)
"storyVideoThumb" gets the read value (0)
```

Why is it inserting the last two values into the wrong fields?

TIA

Comment: i know nothing about objectivec, but are you declaring `addStmt` somewhere else (it look slike it has some kind of global, static scope)?  and, if so, are you sure it's not being defined somewhere else too?

Comment: static sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil; I've amended the question to show full output. This insert works it's just that the last two values go into the wrong fields

Comment: and you don't have any other, similar insert routine that also uses addStmt?

Comment: @andrewcooke - Bingo! Not used to whatever static does (new to Obj-c but familiar with mysql). Make your suggestion an answer and I can accept it it - Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the fame and glory (and points):

addStmt looks to be static and/or global.  i would guess you are using the same variable name elsewhere with a slightly different insert statement.